# How do you run an RSpec independent of the spec helper?

Tags: ruby, rspec

So I'm building a personal library of sorts, meaning I'm making a gem that's comprised of several features and behaviors that I use commonly throughout my projects.

This library will have many different sections, each built to cover one of the specific feature's or behavior's.

One of the things I want the library to do is give me the ability to either import everything, or select the specific features I need for the project I'm working on. To do this I did two things: 1) I set up each individual feature in it's own folder with a special 'import' file that requires everything for that feature in the necessary order, and 2) made two methods at the top level of the gem that access those 'import' files:

```
module MyLibrary 
  def self.import(feature)
    file = get_import_file_for(feature)
    require file
  end

  def self.import_all
    get_all_import_files.each do |file|
      require file
    end
  end
end
```

I want to test these two methods by checking the $LOADED_FEATURES before and after the methods are called to confirm that they were in fact required.

The problem is that I am automatically calling the MyLibrary.import_all method in the spec helper so that everything is loaded for the rest of the tests (which test the specific features):

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  MyLibrary.import_all
end
```

And once this gets called, it seems as though everything is loaded for the remainder of the tests, meaning that when it's time to test the import methods, all the files have already been required, so the tests won't work.

How can I work around this?
Perhaps there is a way to set up one spec file to run independently from the spec helper?
Or somehow set that test to always run first, before those files are required?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps wrap your `MyLibrary.import_all` in that same check for $LOADED_FEATURES, to only run it when you desire?  Or simply check for an ENV variable, so you can run `DONT_IMPORT_ALL=true ./bin/rspec whatever` to avoid the import?

Your spec helper file is just ruby, you can put whatever ruby logic you want in it.

Ah, but if you're asking if there's a way to have *one* rest run, where *some* of the tests are in the context of `MyLibrary.import_all` being run, and *others* are not -- there is not really any good way to do this. Since they are both running in the same ruby process, and `MyLibrary.import_all` is going to do things to that ruby process and it's $LOADED_FEATURES, and there's not really any good way to reliably 'undo' that.

You'll need to run the specs you want to include that and the specs they don't in different runs.

> Perhaps there is a way to set up one spec file to run independently from the spec helper?

Sure, you can do that too -- still subject to the above limitation.

Typically rspec files start with `require 'spec_helper'` at the top. That is why they are running the spec helper. Since this is just ruby, *if* your spec file has that line at the top, it's going to include the spec helper, there's no way around it. But it doesn't neccesarily need that line at the top.

For instance, rspec-rails currently recommends (and sets up as a template) two separate spec helper files `spec_helper.rb` and `rails_helper.rb`.  `spec_helper.rb` includes basic setup that is common to any spec, whether or not it uses rails.  Then `rails_helper.rb` includes only rails-specific setup, and but then does `require 'spec_helper'` itself.  So now some of your specs will have `require 'spec_helper'` at the top (they just require and execute the common config), and while others will have `require 'rails_helper'` at the top -- they execute the rails config *and* the common config.

So if you run `rspec spec/a_file_that_requires_rails_helper.rb` you get the latter; if you run `rspec spec/a_file_that_just_requires_spec_helper.rb`, you get the former.

That's still two different runs -- there's still no way to have one rspec command line run where some specs run in the context of (eg) Rails being initialized, and others don't.  The intended point of this in the rspec-rails recommended case is so you *can* run *just* non-rails tests, and have *speedier* setup time without Rails being initialized.

Hope this helps.